# enhanced for loop comes up null for the variable tName

Tags: search, arraylist, foreach, abstract-class, txt

```
String name = appMenu.promptToyName();
Toys tName = searchByToy(name);
    System.out.print(tName.format());

private Toys searchByToy(String toyName) {
    Toys tName = null;
    
    for(Toys t: toys) {
        if (t.getToyName().toLowerCase().contains(toyName.toLowerCase())) {
            tName = t;
        }
    }
    return tName;
}
```

im doing a search of a arrayList toys, that is an abstract class that calls four other classes of Animals, Figures, Puzzles, and BoardGames

when i use the promptToyName, i enter in a toy name that i have stored into the arrayList from a txt file that has hundreds of different toys, i was expecting it to print out the toy called by search with values that contain the keyword Star, instead whenever i get to the for loop (Toys t: toys) .hasNext() comes up null and the program ends.